# "Alternating between coffee and tea is" or "Alternating between coffee and tea are"

Tags: grammar, plural-forms, singular

If I use this

> Alternating between coffee and tea is good for my health.

or

> Alternating between coffee and tea are good for my health

Which is correct?

Answer (score 6):

*Alternating* is a gerund noun (meaning ***the*** act of switching back and forth). So it's a ***singular*** subject, regardless of the fact that this *particular* "alternating" is further modified by the (syntactically optional) element *between coffee and tea*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Now I understand it's a gerund. I had a hunch that it'd be singular as well. This clears it up.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether you'd understand the concept of "gerund = noun", but I figured it should be reasonable for me not to bother adding a lot more detail unless it was *necessary*. Short and to the point is often best for questions like this, and if any future visitors don't find the answer enlightening they can always post a comment requesting clarification.